# How to level the bumps on the surface of the object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created a human head, on that there are many bumps, which makes my mesh a mess, so what is easy way to level these bumps?
[image: Bumps marked with red ellipse]

[image: Object in edit mode]

Comment: Can you show us the mesh in edit mode?

Comment: Did you try Smooth brush in Sculpt Mode? try uploading the file here, this might help: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You might want to try the smooth and flatten brushes.

Comment: use proportional editing, very simple